# How do I eliminate duplicate city names while adding their total count in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

```
SELECT city, COUNT(pNo) Total
FROM Zip z JOIN Property p ON (z.zipcode = p.zipcode)
WHERE state = 'AL' AND rent <= 500
GROUP BY city, p.zipcode HAVING COUNT(pNo) >= 15
ORDER BY Total DESC, city;
```

Above is my code.  My goal is to not have multiple listings of the same city, but instead have each city display once and if the city has duplicates, add their totals together.  I have tried the DISTINCT clause, but it only eliminates the duplicates without doing doing any adding.  I have tried sticking SUM in the code, too, but I can't quite put my finger on where it should go.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're grouping by zip code, thus creating duplicate city entries (presumably with different counts).

If you want just distinct cities, remove p.zipcode from your GROUP BY and you should be good to go.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have been trying to solve this for hours now.  I am completely new to SQL and it is a bit confusing at times.  That solved it.  I changed my GROUP BY to:

GROUP BY city HAVING COUNT(pNo) >= 15

And it worked like a charm.  Thank you again!

Comment: Just out of curiousity, does the original query even run?  Whenever I get a mismatch between the select and group by clause, I see error messages.  @Anon4567, since you said you are new, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: @Anon4567 -- glad I could, best of luck.

Comment: @DanBracuk it would work in that case, you can group by extra things that aren't in the select, but not have un-aggregated items in the select that aren't in the group by. `select a, b, max(c) from tab group by a` = fail as b isn't aggregated `select a, max(c) from tab group by a, b` = ok (b may cause extra rows but wouldn't cause an error)

Comment: @DanBracuk The original query does run, but its output has duplicate city names (due to the city having multiple zip codes) and the sum of that zip code's properties for rent.  I wasn't sure if it would run, either, due to a mismatch between the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses, but it worked just fine.  sgeddes, do you mind explaining why it works?  I will look into that book.  Thank you!